# how to dim background view

Tags: ios7, modalviewcontroller

trying to dim background view when I work with custom modal view controller I set background color to grey color with 0.5 opacity:

```
- (void)rulesTapped:(id)sender
{
    RulesVC *rulesVC = [[RulesVC alloc] init];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:0.3 alpha:0.5];
    rulesVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
    rulesVC.transitioningDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:rulesVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

but when I then try to set it back to whiteColor (or yellow) while dismissing the modal VC, this dimming keeps in place:

```
- (void) gotItTapped:(id)sender
{

    [self.presentingViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Why? And is there way to dim background (and then remove dimming) view without adding another overlaying view but just operating with existing view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually needed this to be able to put some other UIView in dim view, and that every click outside this dimview, would dismiss both built-in UIView and dimView. What I've discovered, is that for this the best is to imitate a button which is removed from superview upon click:

```
self.dimView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.dimView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2f];
self.dimView.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                0,
                                self.view.frame.size.width,
                                self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.dimView addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(removeDimView)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve it without adding another element to your `UIViewController`. I normally insert an `UIView` which is `setHidden:YES` and alpha 0.0f and `blackColor` as `backgroundColor`. When showing something, I always set it `Hidden:NO` and animate it to opacity 0.6f.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    [self.view setAlpha:0.6];
}];
```

This way it appears not immediately and looks much smoother.